# Is it possible to convert strokes to fills in gs?

Tags: ghostscript

Is there any option to tell gs to convert strokes to fills? Something similar to the "Expand" feature of the Adobe Illustrator? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert strokes to fills, no.

You can use the strokepath PostScript operator, this will replace the current path with a path which encloses the shape that would be drawn if 'stroke' was applied to that path.

The result of strokepath can be used for fill, clip and pathbbox operations, but is not itself suitable for stroking.

Its completely unclear to me why you would want to replace a stroke with a fill, since the two will cover exactly the same area. I'm not at all familiar with Adobe Illustrator so using it as an example doesn't help me. Perhaps you could explain what it is you really want to do, and why you can't do it in the application producing the PostScript, which is almost always a better solution.